# How to calculate the following expectation

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a problem to find the expectation of the following expression,
$$E\left[W_T e^{\int_0^T(W_s)ds}\right].$$
Here, $W_T$ is a Brownian motion. Any suggestions as to how to proceed with it? Many thanks for the help!

Comment: calculate $E(exp^{\int^T W_s ds})$ by using that exponent is gaussian, then differentiate result wrt $T$...I'm assuming $W_t$ is brownian motion, and that you wanted $W_T$ out front

Comment: Got it, many thanks!!!